# Insert text in every Nth cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Here is the sample Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wlO33EWcERa0yYL2xb3BINFt5f441p9MbcB2mPe8eZQ/edit?usp=sharing

I need to insert the text in cell `D1` into every third cell in Column `C`.
You can see in Column `E` what I am trying to do, and I don't want to have to do it by hand.
Essentially, I need to put `%C123H` before each paired `88#` and `T#`.
The `88` is an ID and the `T#` is a device linked to the 88 number. I can then upload the entire list as .txt file into our school inventory system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this Apps Script and it worked:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Destiny Upload');
  var firstRow=1;
  var column=3;
  var destColumn=4;
  var increment=2;
  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
  var values=sheet.getRange(firstRow, column, lastRow,1).getValues();
  var array=[];
  var k=1;
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  for(var i=0;i<lastRow;i++){
    if(i%increment==0){
      array.push("%C123H");
      k++;
    }
     array.push(values[i][0]);
  }
  var outerArray = [];
  for(var j=0;j<array.length;j++){
    var tempArray = [];
    tempArray.push(array[j]);
    Logger.log(array[j]);
    Logger.log(tempArray);
    outerArray.push(tempArray);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, destColumn, array.length, 1).setValues(outerArray);
}
```

Comment: Please remember that you can also [accept your own answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). This way others will benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

I added a sheet called "Erik Help" and entered the formula into cell D1:

```
=FLATTEN(FILTER({IF(A:A="","",$C$1),A:B},A:A<>""))
```

Essentially, I added a virtual column filled with the $C$1 value, then formed a virtual array with this virtual column first, followed by A:B. I used FILTER to get rid of null rows and then used FLATTEN to make a single list.

NOTE: The FLATTEN function is an as-yet-unofficial Google Sheets function.